# memory management in nested blocks

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, objective-c-blocks

References to local variables (including ivars) inside blocks are automatically retained to make sure it remains valid throughout the execution of the block.

That said, would this code lead to a premature deallocation of `self.message`, since the first block does not reference it, even though the second block does? Or is it smart enough to know it should be retained?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    /* snip */
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if ([self.message.ID isEqualToString:@"foobar"]) {
            /* snip */
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I believe the first block does reference it, but not explicitly - it's accessed within the outer scope - that's just another detail that it's also inside the second, inner scope.

Comment: It works with nested blocks, but `self` is retained, not `self.message`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A block captures all variables inside it, including nested blocks. In short: it does the "right" thing.

In this particular case, note that it's `self` that's being captured, not `self.message`.